# Return a whole row of data if a cell in the row matches a criteria

Tags: vba, excel, lookup

I have a workbook with two sheets.
The first one (Sheet 1) contains a lot of data (~70.000 rows and columns A-G).
The second one (Sheet 2) is empty.

The thing is that I need to copy the whole row of data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 if a cell matches a certain criteria. I'll try to be specific:

In Sheet 1 column B has some different values. If the value in a cell in column B is `5 Mathias` I need to get that whole row of data (columns A-G) copied to Sheet 2. It would be really neat if this can result in a block of data in Sheet 2 which looks just like Sheet 1 except for the fact, that they all share the same value in column B. What would be even cooler is if I can add in more data rows in the bottom of Sheet 1 every month and Sheet 2 then updates itself.

I've tried with lookups so far but without any real luck.

I hope that it's possible and that I've explained it in a decent way!

Answer (score 0):

The below code checks the data in `Sheet1`, then moves the data over to `Sheet2` based on the listed criteria. Let me know if you can incorporate it into your workbook.

```
Sub CopyFromSheetToOther()
    Dim wsOrigin As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range

    Const CRITERIA As String = "Matt"

    Set wsOrigin = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    wsDest.Cells.ClearContents
    Set rngData = wsOrigin.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    rngData.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=CRITERIA
    rngData.Copy wsDest.Range("A1")

    wsOrigin.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```